# how to use cross join in raw query of sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I've googling and found that i also can do Cross Join in SQlite Android, i've tried but the result was null. Is there something wrong with my program? or actually cross join cannot be applied in raw query? thanks for your help.

Note : before i use cross join i try to send a table (in JSONArray Form) and it's working, so i assume it happens when i use cross join in my code.

Here's my program :

```
private JSONArray getResults()
{
    Context context = this;

    String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantin1.db"));// Set path to your database

    //String myTable = DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME;//Set name of your table

    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    //String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME + " CROSS JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME, null );

    JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
        {
            if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString() );


    Intent pass_data = new Intent(this,BluetoothOut.class);

    pass_data.putExtra("pindah",resultSet.toString());
    startActivity(pass_data);

    return resultSet;
}
}
```

Here's my database helper :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="ekantins.db";

//tabel order
public static final String ORDER_TABLE_NAME="tb_order";
public static final String COL_1="ORDERID";
public static final String COL_2="USERID";
public static final String COL_3="PASSWORD";
public static final String COL_4="MEJA";
public static final String COL_5="TOPUP";
public static final String COL_6="SALDO";

//tabel lineitems
public static final String LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME="tb_lineitems";
public static final String COL1 = "FOODID";
public static final String COL2 = "PRICE";
public static final String COL3 = "NUM";
public static final String COL4 = "RES";




DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ORDER_TABLE_NAME + " (ORDERID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERID TEXT ,PASSWORD TEXT, MEJA TEXT, TOPUP TEXT, SALDO TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME + " (FOODID TEXT ,PRICE TEXT, NUM TEXT, RES TEXT, ORDERID_FK INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ORDER_TABLE_NAME ); //Drop older table if exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME ); //Drop older table if exists
    onCreate(db);
}
public void delete (String FOODID) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL1 + "= '" + FOODID + "'");

    //Close the database
    database.close();
}
public String Sum() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {"SUM("+COL4+")" };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    String result = "";
    int index_SUM = cursor.getColumnIndex("SUM("+COL4+")");
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + cursor.getString(index_SUM)  + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String getTopup() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_5+" FROM "+ORDER_TABLE_NAME,null);
    String topup="";
    for(cr.moveToFirst();!cr.isAfterLast();cr.moveToNext()){
        topup=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(COL_5));
    }
    cr.close();
    return topup;
}

public String getSaldo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_6+" FROM "+ORDER_TABLE_NAME,null);
    String saldo="";
    for(cr.moveToFirst();!cr.isAfterLast();cr.moveToNext()){
        saldo=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(COL_6));
    }
    cr.close();
    return saldo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong with my program?

There doesn't appear from just a quick look.

> or actually cross join cannot be applied in raw query?

I don't believe there is any such restriction.

I believe the issue is simply that you have no rows in the **tb_lineitems** table. Hence, `SELECT * FROM tb_order` will return rows. But that there are no joined rowsreturned when you JOIN the tb_lineitems table.

For example using (***note how no line_items are inserted as the SQL is commented out***):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_order;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_order (ORDERID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,USERID TEXT ,PASSWORD TEXT, MEJA TEXT, TOPUP TEXT, SALDO TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_lineitems;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_lineitems (FOODID TEXT ,PRICE TEXT, NUM TEXT, RES TEXT, ORDERID_FK INTEGER);
INSERT INTO tb_order VALUES
    (null,'Fred','password','meja001','topup001','saldo001'),
    (null,'Mary','password','meja002','topup002','saldo002'),
    (null,'Bert','password','meja003','topup003','saldo003');
/*
INSERT INTO tb_lineitems VALUES
    ('food001','10.30','1','res001',1),
    ('food002','11.30','1','res002',1),
    ('food002','11.30','1','res002',2)
    ;
*/
SELECT * FROM tb_order;
SELECT * FROM tb_lineitems;
SELECT * FROM tb_order 
      CROSS 
JOIN tb_lineitems 
;
```

results in the following 3 outputs :-

[image]
[image]
[image]

Remove the comments from the inserts for the 3 tb_lineitems and the results are :-

[image]
[image]
[image]

- Note that the results of the CROSS JOIN are no DIFFERENT than the results of a JOIN though, as per :-
- > If the join-operator is "CROSS JOIN", "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" or a comma
  >   (",") and there is no ON or USING clause, then the result of the join
  >   is simply the cartesian product of the left and right-hand datasets.
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SELECT - 1. Determination of input data (FROM clause processing).](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

### Re Comment :-

> I've checked the database, tb_line items and and tb_order are not
>   empty.

**Which database have you checked? You are attempting to use 2 according to closer inspection of your code.**

In the database helper you have defined the database as **ekantins.db**. However, you open a database named **ekantin1.db** in your `getResults` method.

In the text below note the following code :-

```
    //String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantin1.db"));// Set path to your database
    String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantins.db"));// Set path to your database
```

Running a minor adaptation of your code and only using 1 database

- two methods added to the database helper to add orders and lineitems (not included)
- The following code being used as the activity (i.e. your code + a little more)

  - The attempt to start another activity commented out
  - The `getResults` method being invoked twice i.e. before there is any data and after

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        JSONArray r1 = getResults();

        String sql = " SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME + " CROSS JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME;


        cursor = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

        // Only add data once
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME) < 1) {

            mDBHlpr.addOrder("Fred", "password", "m001", "t001", "s001");
            mDBHlpr.addOrder("Mary", "password", "m001", "t001", "s001");
            mDBHlpr.addOrder("Bert", "password", "m001", "t001", "s001");

            cursor = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

            mDBHlpr.addLineItem("F001", "10.30", "1", "1", 1);
            mDBHlpr.addLineItem("F002", "11.30", "2", "2", 1);
            mDBHlpr.addLineItem("F003", "12.30", "3", "3", 2);

            cursor = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);
        }

        JSONArray r2 = getResults();
    }

    private JSONArray getResults()
    {
        Context context = this;

        //String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantin1.db"));// Set path to your database

        String myPath = String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("ekantins.db"));// Set path to your database

        String myTable = DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME;//Set name of your table

        SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        //SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase();
        //String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.ORDER_TABLE_NAME + " CROSS JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.LINEITEMS_TABLE_NAME, null );

        JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

            for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
            {
                if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                        {
                            Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                        }
                    }
                    catch( Exception e )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString() );


        /*
        Intent pass_data = new Intent(this,BluetoothOut.class);

        pass_data.putExtra("pindah",resultSet.toString());
        startActivity(pass_data);
        */

        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

The results is :-

```
08-04 07:05:36.895 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio D/TAG_NAME: []
08-04 07:05:36.895 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@5343e554
    <<<<<
08-04 07:05:36.907 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@53441ce0
    <<<<<
08-04 07:05:36.915 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@53437acc
    0 {
       ORDERID=1
       USERID=Fred
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F001
       PRICE=10.30
       NUM=1
       RES=1
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    1 {
       ORDERID=1
       USERID=Fred
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F002
       PRICE=11.30
       NUM=2
       RES=2
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    2 {
       ORDERID=1
       USERID=Fred
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F003
       PRICE=12.30
       NUM=3
       RES=3
       ORDERID_FK=2
    }
    3 {
       ORDERID=2
       USERID=Mary
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F001
       PRICE=10.30
       NUM=1
       RES=1
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    4 {
       ORDERID=2
       USERID=Mary
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F002
       PRICE=11.30
       NUM=2
       RES=2
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    5 {
       ORDERID=2
       USERID=Mary
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F003
       PRICE=12.30
       NUM=3
       RES=3
       ORDERID_FK=2
    }
    6 {
       ORDERID=3
       USERID=Bert
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F001
       PRICE=10.30
       NUM=1
       RES=1
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    7 {
       ORDERID=3
       USERID=Bert
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F002
       PRICE=11.30
       NUM=2
       RES=2
       ORDERID_FK=1
    }
    8 {
       ORDERID=3
       USERID=Bert
       PASSWORD=password
       MEJA=m001
       TOPUP=t001
       SALDO=s001
       FOODID=F003
       PRICE=12.30
       NUM=3
       RES=3
       ORDERID_FK=2
    }
    <<<<<
08-04 07:05:36.919 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio D/TAG_NAME: 1
    Fred
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F001
    10.30
    1
    1
    1
08-04 07:05:36.923 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio D/TAG_NAME: 1
    Fred
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F002
    11.30
    2
    2
    1
    1
    Fred
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F003
    12.30
    3
    3
    2
    2
    Mary
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F001
    10.30
    1
    1
    1
    2
    Mary
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F002
    11.30
    2
    2
    1
    2
    Mary
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F003
    12.30
    3
    3
    2
    3
    Bert
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F001
    10.30
    1
    1
    1
    3
    Bert
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F002
    11.30
    2
    2
    1
    3
    Bert
    password
    m001
    t001
    s001
    F003
    12.30
    3
    3
    2
08-04 07:05:36.927 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio D/TAG_NAME: [{"PRICE":"10.30","RES":"1","ORDERID":"1","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"1","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F001","USERID":"Fred"},{"PRICE":"11.30","RES":"2","ORDERID":"1","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"2","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F002","USERID":"Fred"},{"PRICE":"12.30","RES":"3","ORDERID":"1","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"2","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"3","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F003","USERID":"Fred"},{"PRICE":"10.30","RES":"1","ORDERID":"2","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"1","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F001","USERID":"Mary"},{"PRICE":"11.30","RES":"2","ORDERID":"2","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"2","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F002","USERID":"Mary"},{"PRICE":"12.30","RES":"3","ORDERID":"2","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"2","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"3","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F003","USERID":"Mary"},{"PRICE":"10.30","RES":"1","ORDERID":"3","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"1","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F001","USERID":"Bert"},{"PRICE":"11.30","RES":"2","ORDERID":"3","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"1","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"2","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F002","USERID":"Bert"},{"PRICE":"12.30","RES":"3","ORDERID":"3","SALDO":"s001","MEJA":"m001","ORDERID_FK":"2","PASSWORD":"password","NUM":"3","TOPUP":"t001","FOODID":"F003","USERID":"Bert"}]
08-04 07:05:36.951 1494-1494/pra.playrawaudio I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.getLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompat.getLayoutDirection
```

**The results showing that there is nothing wrong with the provided code nor with the query. i.e. when data exists results are returned**

Comment: I've checked the database, tb_line items and and tb_order are not empty. @MikeT